# How to integrate youtube live streaming API into my application

Tags: react-native, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

#### How To: Integrate Youtube Live Streaming API

**My Goal:**
I want to integrate the Youtube Live Streaming API into my application to allow users to go live within my App and it should be stored on the Youtube Servers.

My user will go live inside my App and I want to use Youtube Live Streaming API instead of other third party APIs like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/).

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is your first question, please consider the platform rules and standards when posting a question.
Explain your specific situation and the problem you want to solve. Add Code Snippets if you have some, elaborate the circumstances and explain what you want to know.
Please read following guide if you want to learn more on: [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)